# ArgumentError: Missing :controller key on routes definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :items

  root 'items#index'


  get 'items/index', to:'items/index'
  get 'items/show', to:'items/show'
  get 'items/new', to:'items/new'
  get 'items/edit', to:'items/edit'

  post '/items/create', to:'items/create'
  post '/items/update', to:'items/update'
  post '/items/destroy', to:'items/destroy'

  get '/users/userindex', to: 'users/userindex'
  get '/users/usershow', to: 'users/usershow'
  get '/users/usernew', to: 'users/usernew'

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ArgumentError: Missing :controller key

The notation used to map the routes to a controller's action is `controller#action`, not `controller/action`. Change your routes accordingly

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :items

  root 'items#index'

  get 'items/index', to:'items#index'
  get 'items/show', to:'items#show'
  get 'items/new', to:'items#new'
  get 'items/edit', to:'items#edit'
  post '/items/create', to:'items#create'
  post '/items/update', to:'items#update'
  post '/items/destroy', to:'items#destroy'
  get '/users/userindex', to: 'users#userindex'
  get '/users/usershow', to: 'users#usershow'
  get '/users/usernew', to: 'users#usernew'
end
```

Moreover, you should take a look at [*Resourceful Routing*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). You have most of the routes declared wrongly. In other words, they wouldn't be needed when you already have them with `resources`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: How does Rails route the request if we omit the `to:` symbol?